# Does order of class selectors matter?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Assume that I have an element as below:

```
<div class="A B C" />
```

And in the scss stylesheet, I have the styles as below:

```
.A {
  &.B {

  }
  &.C {
  }
}

.B {
  &.A {
  }
  &.C {
  }
}

.C {
  &.A {
  }
  &.B {
  }
}
```

What are the CSS styles the element will pick up and how does it work?

Comment: What is the result when you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these would be applied, since the order is not relevant. The later rules will overwrite the previous ones if they contain settings for the same parameters, just due to the order in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

All of these styles will be picked up. Order of classes does not matter. The CSS this will translate to is basically:

```
.A.B {
}
.A.C {
}

.B.A {
}
.B.C {
}

.C.A {
}
.C.B {
}
```

...and because it has all three classes, they all apply.